# SQL-query error date

Tags: mysql, sql

why does MySQL give me **#1063 - Wrong column specification for column 'Date'** error if I want to import this query? What I need to have in that row is Date with format: YYYY/MM/DD. Can someone help me and explain whats wrong and why this is wrong so I can learn :) Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    Employee_number INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Lastname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    Firstname VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    Residence VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    Skilllevel TINYINT NOT NULL,
    Salary DECIMAL NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Direct_hours (
    Date DATE AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY Employee_number INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee (Employee_number),
    FOREIGN KEY Project_number INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Project (Project_number)
);
CREATE TABLE Indirect_hours (
    Date DATE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY Employee_number INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee (Employee_number),
    Type VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    Number INT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    Customer_number INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Client_name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    Residence VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Skilllevel (
    Levels TINYINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY Employee_number INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee (Employee_number),
    Description VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    Hourly_rate TINYINT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Project (
    Project_number INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY Employee_number INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee (Employee_number),
    FOREIGN KEY Customer_number INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Customer (Customer_number),
    Hourly_rate TINYINT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: `DATE AUTO_INCREMENT`?? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Oh snap :/. I need glasses

Comment: This is not the only problem. You can not set a foreign key on a not existing column.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel where do u see that?

Comment: Everywhere! See examples here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @JeBoyAbi... the `project` table needs to be created before the `direct_hours` table, more strictly speaking, before we create the foreign key constraint in `direct_hours` that references `project`. Similarly, `customer` needs to be created before `project`. (We can play tricks with `foreign_key_checks`, but I wouldn't recommend it, just create the tables in the correct order.

Comment: Also be aware of problems that you can run into with mixed case table names and identifier case sensitivity ...MySQL Reference Manual recommends: "*it is best to adopt a consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to databases and tables using lowercase names. This convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use.*"  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html